# What is a typical Teimani Seder like?

Tags: minhag, passover-seder-hagada, yemenite-temani

Inspired by the comments [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101397/what-is-required-at-the-seder/101399#comment338783_101397), I realized how little I know about what other customs' Sedarim are like. As an Ashkenazi, I'd only ever participated in Ashkenazi Sedarim. As such, I'd like to explore what other traditions do on this night.

What is a typical Teimani (Yemenite) Seder like? What sorts of minhagim are widely practiced uniquely in Teimani communities?

Particularly those who have attended both Teimani Sedarim and other traditions: what were some of the main differences you saw?

---

For other posts in this series, click [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+user%3A9682+what+is+a+typical+seder+like).

Answer (score 7):

These differences are from my teimani friend who has been to both ashkenazi and sefardi Sedarim.

•  a seider plate isn’t used at the seider; rather the vegetables are set around the table, and the other foods are put in front of each person.

•  charoses is the only dip.

•  some have the youngest read Mah Nishtanah in Arabic (this is an older custom that was dropped by some teimanim).

•  the entire Haggadah is read out loud by everybody, in the Mishnah trup.

•  in dayenu, one person reads ‘eilu...’ and everybody else answers ‘dayenu’.

•  after ‘nishmas kol chai’, shir hashirim is read, and piyutim and Chad Gadya are not.

•  the afikoman isn’t stolen/ hidden.

•  there is no ‘kos shel eliyahu’.

•  a fifth cup is optional, not prohibited, and those who drink it say ‘hodu LaShem ki tov, ki le’olam chasdo...’